# How can I filter an array from UISearchController

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I try to filter an array from UISearchController, and it failed. my first attempt is I try to make two array the first array is to store the data and the second array to hold the filter. than make my numberOfRowsInSection count as a filter array but it still not working, what went wrong?. here is show you my code .

```
    // This is in my PopularViewController
    let store = PopularStore()
    var timer: Timer?
    var page = 1
    var hasMoreMovies = true
    let dataSource = PopularDataSource()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchMovie(page: page)
    }

    private func fetchMovie(page: Int) {
        showLoadingView()
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false, block: { _ in
            self.store.fetchMovie(page: page, completion: { [weak self] result in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.dismissLoadingView()
                switch result {
                case .success(let movies):
                    if movies.count < 100 { self.hasMoreMovies = false }
                    self.dataSource.items.append(contentsOf: movies)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .none)
            })
        })
    }

    extension PopularViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if !searchText.isEmpty {
            dataSource.filterMovie = dataSource.items.filter({ $0.title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased() )})

            dataSource.filterMovie = dataSource.items
          }
       }
    }

    // This is in my UITableViewDataSource
    class PopularDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    var items = [Movie]()
    var filterMovie = [Movie]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filterMovie.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PopularCell.cellID, for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain in detail what exactly failed and is not working.

Comment: Did you set the VC as delegate for the SearchBar?

Comment: @Andrea yes I already set the delegate

Comment: first thing first @koen when I change the datasource count into filterMovie.count the data is not display. but when I set may datasource count into items.count, the data is being display. and since I try to make the numberOfRowInSection count is the filterMovie I think why is not working because I try to filter no array is try to append. it just my Guess

Comment: @ferryawijayanto when you change the property data Source of the tableView you have to call the methods reloadData(), to force an update of the tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `filterMovie` is the main data source assign the whole list (`items`) or the filtered items depending on `searchText` and reload the table view

```
extension PopularViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
   func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
       if !searchText.isEmpty {
           dataSource.filterMovie = dataSource.items.filter{ $0.title.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
       } else {
           dataSource.filterMovie = dataSource.items
       }
       self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
}
```

If the deployment target is iOS 13 consider to use `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` to populate the table view. It's very fast and you get smart animations.

Comment: hey @vadian thank you it work like a charm haha, thank you for your help :)